# Clean User input in ruby

Tags: ruby, input

As I'm slowly writing my logging script, I've hit sort of a snag.  I've gotten the bulk of the program to work, but now I'm just adding in some creature comforts, such as some limits on what you can enter and whatnot.

```
def HitsPerMinute()

print "Is there a specific hour you would like to see: "
STDOUT.flush
mhour = spectime = gets.strip

 #mhour = mhour.to_s
 if mhour == '' or mhour == '\n' or (mhour =~ /[a-z]|[A-Z].*/)
   puts "Please enter an hour you would like to see."
   HitsPerMinute()
 #else
   #mhour = mhour.to_i
  end
    mstart = 00
    mend = 59

    mstart.upto(mend) { |x|
     moment = "#{rightnow}:#{zeroadder(mhour)}:#{zeroadder(x)}".strip
     print "Server hits at '#{moment}: "
     puts `cat /home/*/var/*/logs/transfer.log | grep -c #{moment}`
      x = x.to_i
      x = x.next
     }
 end

HitsPerMinute()
```

For the most part it works fine and well, except it seems to store the variables that are entered before.  As shown here.

```
Is there a specific hour you would like to see:  
Please enter an hour you would like to see.
Is there a specific hour you would like to see:  
Please enter an hour you would like to see.
Is there a specific hour you would like to see: d
Please enter an hour you would like to see.
Is there a specific hour you would like to see: 13
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:13:00: 48
[...]
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:13:59: 187
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:0d:00: 0
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:0d:01: 0
[...]
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:0d:57: 0
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:0d:58: 0
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012:0d:59: 0
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012::00: 0
Server hits at '10/Oct/2012::01: 0
[...]
```

I use .strip on my input variables, but that doesn't seem to do anything for this issue.  I tried using .flush but that doesn't seem to do much either.  How is it even storing multiple variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the HitsPerMinute method is called several times, when the if condition ends it continues the run, do it in a loop instead

```
def HitsPerMinute()

  STDOUT.flush
  mhour = ''

  while mhour == '' or mhour == '\n' or (mhour =~ /[a-z]|[A-Z].*/) do
    puts "Please enter an hour you would like to see."
    mhour = spectime = gets.strip
  end

  mstart = 00
  mend = 59

  mstart.upto(mend) { |x|
    moment = "#{rightnow}:#{zeroadder(mhour)}:#{zeroadder(x)}".strip
    print "Server hits at '#{moment}: "
    puts `cat /home/*/var/*/logs/transfer.log | grep -c #{moment}`
    x = x.to_i
    x = x.next
  }
end

HitsPerMinute()
```

- update about variables:

it is not storing several values on mhour variable, mhour has only one value each time the method is called. User is answered to enter a new value before the method reaches its end, so when it finally ends, the previous calls continue its run, maybe this example helps to understand:

```
def method(i)
  if i < 5
    method(i+1)
  end
  puts i
end

method(1)
```

output:

```
$ ruby /tmp/test.rb
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: I have to ask though, how is it storing the multiple variables?  It isn't set as an array, and I would be really surprised if it was storing them like ' \n d\n13'.

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it helps to understand it